# Endogenity in logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, endogeneity

Consider a logistic regression model built to assess female work participation with household income included as an explanatory variable.  Would household income be an endogenous variable in this context? If so how do I control for the endogeneity?

Comment: Can you clarify what you intend to do with the resulting model? Edogeneity isn't a problem (and doesn't need to be controlled for) if you're merely trying to guess whether particular households have an adult female participating in the workforce (say for a marketing campaign.) But if you're trying to show support for the existence of a causal relationship between female workforce participation and household income, that's a different story.

Comment: Since it is a cross section data that is being considered it would not be possible to make observations at different points of time. The univariate analysis for the decision to participate or not participate taking income as a variable shows a non-significant p value. As such income has not been included in the multivariate analysis. Since the households are agricultural households with total family income being a result of joint participation it is not possible to separate the earnings of the male and female members. Is there any other method to solve this problem?

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you would have omitted variable bias there if you only have variable whether woman supplies labor or not and total labor income of the household. Total income is partly composed of the earnings of woman in the family, assuming you have family with at least two adults / earners.

One method to eliminate this is to have a sample where women are not working at the start of the observation period. They are observed for next T periods and event (0/1 coding) occurs if they start to supply labor or not. There earnings can be used since they have not contributed to that.

Economic model could be a system of several equations where decision to supply labor is affected by both household and individual characteristics.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a classic case of a particular omitted variable bias called the Heckman sample selection problem.

Attrition is meaningful here, as the decision to not work may be based on house characteristics, and the wage (the woman would have earned had she worked or the observed wage) potentially are driven by individual characteristics.

[Notes on the Heckman Selection Issues.](https://eml.berkeley.edu/~bhhall/e244/sampsel.pdf)